# C++ DIR * dir need to use to only one working at a time

Tags: c++, directory

Hello I am programming using code block using C++, All I want is to use opendir twice and it is only opening once both chunks of codes are working but only the top one works and not the bottom one.
Please some one help me only one dir is working at a time:
I want one `DIR` to work and give me values to drill down in to another Dir and get values.

```
int main()
{   std::string EmployeeNumbr[1000];
    std::string DocumentName[1000];
    std::string Path = "C:\\EmpFiles\\";
    int f;
    int j;

  DIR *dir;
   struct dirent * file;
```

Comment: How did you determine that the bottom block of code does not "work"? What is the expected and actual behavior? Did you enable compiler warnings? Your compiler should scream at you that `f` and `j` are being used uninitialized.

Comment: You should also use safer C++ data structures such as vectors and the std::filesystem API.

Comment: I am using both Dir one by one and they are working seperately when put together only the one on top works. Note there are two Dirs and both copying directry from windows.

Comment: All this is already packaged into [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) to provide a standardized way to [iterate over directory entries](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) and even doing it [recursively](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator). If you do want to use `opendir`, `readdir` and `closedir`, package them into a class to make usage easier: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Mz15bh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `f` and `j` uninitialized. For `f` this probably works by accident, as the stack is still relatively fresh.

However, by the time you start using `j` the stack has been thoroughly polluted and your uninitialized use returns random stack garbage.

Any half-decent compiler should yell at you if you do this, so please figure out how to upgrade warning levels (either `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on GCC/Clang, or `-W4` on MSVC)